# issue in pod install after adding blinkId library

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native 0.60.5

and after I added this module [BlinkId](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-react-native) via `npm i blinkid-react-native` then link it using `react-native link blinkid-react-native`

Now when I navigate to ios folder and run `pod install` I got this error

[image]

if I removed `use_native_modules` then `pod install` works fine but I got another error

> null is not an object evaluating _RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction

any help with this?